# android - using PinnedHeaderListView inside a viewPager

Tags: android, tabs, android-listview, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

background:
using `actionBarSherlock` , i have a viewpager which has a `PinnedHeaderListView` in one of its pages.

the viewPager has 3 tabs, as seen in the tabs pager fragment example.

the problem:
for some reason , the `PinnedHeaderListView` doesn't show the upper header (no matter how much i scroll down/up) unless i switch to the last tab and back again to the first tab (which has the `PinnedHeaderListView`) .

here's a screenshot to illustrate the problem:

http://tinypic.com/r/2w49rnq/6

it should always have a header on the top of the list , for example :

http://tinypic.com/r/m756s7/6

my question is : why does it happen and how can i fix it ?